# How to write a program that, given a metric, finds the locally flat coordinates at an arbitrary point?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces

In A. Zee's *Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell* on page 90, he encourages the reader to do this:

[image]

Is that even possible without having a formula parsing and manipulation engine?

For example the following metrics:

Sphere:
$$
g_{ij} = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \text{sin}^2x_1\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Torus:
$$
\xi_{ij} = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & (1+\text{cos}(x_1))^2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Hyperbolic plane $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1x_2$:
$$
\eta_{ij} = \left(\begin{matrix}(1+x_2)^2 & 0 \\ 0 & (1+x_1)^2\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Zee's simple example on page 83:
$$
\chi_{ij} = \left(\begin{matrix}(1+ax_1+cx_2)^2 & (ax_1+cx_2)(bx_2+cx_1) \\ (ax_1+cx_2)(bx_2+cx_1) & (1+bx_2+cx_1)^2\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Given an arbitrary point $P=(x_1, x_2)$, the program needs to make a coordinate transform that makes the metric locally flat, i.e. $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$. To do that, I first need a formula parser, right?

Somehow I think I don't understand the exercise correctly.

Comment: I suppose so, if you want a symbolic expression at the end.

Comment: And if not? (Sorry if this is a complete noob question..)

Comment: @ZhenLin sorry, forgot to add your name

Comment: @ZhenLin So it's a program that just diagonalizes the matrix at some point? Is it really so easy? This would be a linear algebra exercise.